# Jtwig How to obtain HttpSession / HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, spring, session, template-engine, jtwig

Recently began using Jtwig and have no idea how to easily obtain session, servletrequest, remote user and so on.
In Thymeleaf, for example, it can be done that way:

```
<span th:text="${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}"></span>
...
<p th:text="${#httpSession.getValue(...)}"></p>
```

Documentation nor Google was not able to answer my question. Probably, this is not implemented (yet?) and i always must put necessary objects manually into the ModelMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request object is added to the model for free. For example, to access the remote user:

```
{{ request.remoteUser }}
```

To access a session attribute:

```
{{ request.session.getAttribute('user') }}
```

Basically, follow the servlet API starting with the request variable.

Comment: Thanks, very appreciated! But i wonder, why isn't this mentioned in documentation? And is there something else that being added to the Model? (I've tried to set some breakpoints and had no luck to catch something).

Comment: A-ha. Seems i figured it out myself. There are beans, theme and request. JtwigView.renderMergedTemplateModel.